# Limiting mysql table to a sertain size and automatically deleting oldest entries

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table)

Is it possible ( and how ) to put a limit on a MySQL table ( let's say 100'000 ) and deleting the old entries when limit reaches?

Meaning, when I have 100'000 entries and the 100'001 appears, the entry with the smallest ID is deleted and the new one is created ( with the new ID of course ).

I want MySQL to handle this on it's own, so no outside scripts need to interfere.

I need this for logging purposes, meaning, I want to keep logs only for a certain time period, let's say a week. Maybe it is possible for MySQL just to delete entries, that are older then 1 week on it's own?

Comment: mysql can schedule things on its own, or you can use a cron job to do it for you. you could also use a trigger to intercept the inserts and start the cleanup at that time as well.

Comment: You can use a trigger or set up a job. Related topics: [How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table), [What is the best way to delete old rows from MySQL on a rolling basis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472167/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-old-rows-from-mysql-on-a-rolling-basis)

Comment: +1 @njk - this is the best method of handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose triggers. This is the best way of insuring that at each insert the maximum table size is being taken into account.

**Possible duplicate** of [How can I set a maximum number of rows in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048001/how-can-i-set-a-maximum-number-of-rows-in-mysql-table)

From that accepted answer:

---

Try to make a restriction on adding a new record to a table. Raise an error when a new record is going to be added.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt >= 25 THEN
    CALL sth(); -- raise an error
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note, that COUNT operation may be slow on big InnoDb tables.

On MySQL 5.5 you can use SIGNAL statement to raise an error.

Comment: I tried to change `CALL sth();` to `DELETE FROM one ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1` but it gives errors. Can it be done that way?