# Trigger to archive data after one year

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I've created a mysql table to hold some records (id, timestamp, fname..etc). The main goal is to hold this info for 1 year and then archive it. I have no experience with triggers but I'm wondering is it possible to use the timestamp in a trigger so that a year from the timestamp it gets moved to an archive table?

Comment: Instead of using a trigger (what, if nothing happens to start the trigger? you should think about using a daily or weekly job (this can be started by the operating system).

Comment: share if you have written something. We can not write complete trigger for you!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html):

> A trigger is defined to activate when a statement inserts, updates, or
>   deletes rows in the associated table. These row operations are trigger
>   events.

Time passed isn't one of those trigger events.

You have to create a process to do that job for you.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9472167/1385896) for some approaches to do that.